# ASP.NET MVC C# routes.MapRoute not working

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am altering an ASP.NET, MVC, C# application but a `routes.MapRoute` entry isn't working as expected. In my Global.asax.cs file I have the following two routes -

```
routes.MapRoute(
            "MyRoute1", // Route name
            "{controller}/{action}/{something}/{name}/{id}/{myParameterA}", 
            new { controller = "MyController", action = "MyActionA", category = "something", name = "name", id = "id", myParameterA = "myParameterA" });


routes.MapRoute(
            "MyRoute2", // Route name
            "{controller}/{action}/{something}/{name}/{id}/{myParameterB}", 
            new { controller = "MyController", action = "MyActionB", category = "something", name = "name", id = "id", myParameterB = UrlParameter.Optional } );
```

The code in my controller looks like this -

```
    public ActionResult MyActionA(string something, string name, string id, string myParameterA)
    {
       //do cool stuff!
    }

    public ActionResult MyActionB(string something, string name, string id, string myParameterB)
    {
       //do awesome stuff!
    }
```

When I call `MyActionB`, the final parameter `myParameterB` is coming into the Controller as **null** even when the parameter is in the URL - (example: /MyController/MyActionB/aThing/aName/123/456).

I *do* want the final parameter ('456' in my above example) to be optional.

`MyActionA` is working fine.

Any suggestions would be appreciated! 
Also, is there a good reference out there on how `routes.MapRoute` works?
Thank you!

Comment: What happens if you replace the routes order ?

Comment: Thanks for your question Cristi! When I change the order, `MyActionB` works, but a null gets sent to the final parameter of `MyActionA`.

Comment: If your action is defined in the URL, why do you even have two routes mapped? I suspect, as @levelnis pointed out, the second is never actually being matched.

Comment: Hey roryf, you said - "your action is defined in the URL"? Can you explain what you mean by that? Don't I need two routes for two differently named actions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because there is nothing to distinguish between those 2 routes once you replace the parameters with strings in the route itself. If you add a static part to the routes you should be able to differentiate between them.

```
routes.MapRoute(
        "MyRoute1", // Route name
        "{controller}/{action}/{something}/{name}/{id}/firstroute/{myParameterA}", 
        new { controller = "MyController", action = "MyActionA", category = "something", name = "name", id = "id", myParameterA = "myParameterA" });


routes.MapRoute(
        "MyRoute2", // Route name
        "{controller}/{action}/{something}/{name}/{id}/secondroute/{myParameterB}", 
        new { controller = "MyController", action = "MyActionB", category = "something", name = "name", id = "id", myParameterB = UrlParameter.Optional } );
```

See if that works.

Comment: Given that the routes go to specific, different actions, you could also fix the start of the route, e.g. `"my-first-route/{something}/{name}/{id}/{myParameterA}"`

Comment: Thank levelnis! Your solution worked! (I actually used what you had in the comments section).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure but I think swap the two around, when you set "myParameterA = "myParameterA"" on the first, you're assigning a default value, when you pass /MyController/MyActionB/aThing/aName/123/456 the url is mapped to the first, but the number 456 is not compatible with the default string value - and so is passed as null.

EDIT: oh and for a good reference, the Apress Pro MVC 3 has an excellent chapter on this - Safari Informit.